# IN clause with large list in OpenJpa causing too complex statement

Tags: db2, openjpa, in-clause

I have to create a named query where I need to group my results by some fields and also using an IN clause to limit my results.

The it looks something like this

```
SELECT new MyDTO(e.objID) FROM Entity e WHERE e.objId IN (:listOfIDs) GROUP BY e.attr1, e.attr2
```

I'm using OpenJPA and IBM DB2. In some cases my List of IDs can be very large (>80.000 IDs) and then the generated SQL statement becomes too complex for DB2, because the final generated statement prints out all IDs, like this:

```
 SELECT new MyDTO(e.objID) FROM Entity e WHERE e.objId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...) GROUP BY e.attr1, e.attr2
```

Is there any good way to handle this kind of query? A possible Workaround would be to write the IDs in a temporary table and then using the IN clause on this table.

Comment: JPA is really designed more for "few" records (which can still be a lot), and that set size isn't it.  What are you doing that you're messing with that many records at once?  You're probably better off bulk-loading into a table to join to (similar to the existing answer, but there are special tools for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all of the values in a table and rewrite the query as a join.  This will not only solve your query problem, it should be more efficient as well.

```
declare global temporary table ids (
   objId int
) with replace on commit preserve rows;

--If this statement is too long, use a couple of insert statements.
insert into session.ids values
    (1,2,3,4,....);

select new mydto(e.objID) 
    from entity e 
    join session.ids i on 
       e.objId = i.objId 
group by e.attr1, e.attr2;
```

Comment: This could work, but how do I access the temporary table in my JPQL statement? I can't access "session" directly because it is not recognized as an entity.

Comment: So this seems to be the best solution. I couldn't use a global temporary table, but my approach works. I'm using a "normal" table and filling it on demand with the list of ids.